# Refactoring with Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, refactoring

I implemented the following class `DateBucket` that has a method called `bucketize`. This method returns a list of `DateBucket` where each `DateBucket` in the list is between the dates `fromDate` and `toDate` and uses `bucketSize` and `bucketSizeUnit` as steps to set the values of the `from` and `to` `DateBucket` variables.

```
class DateBucket {
    final Instant from;
    final Instant to;

    public static List<DateBucket> bucketize(
        ZonedDateTime fromDate, 
        ZonedDateTime toDate, 
        int bucketSize, 
        ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit
        ) {
    List<DateBucket> buckets = new ArrayList<>();
    
    boolean reachedDate = false;
    
    for (int i = 0; !reachedDate; i++) {
        ZonedDateTime minDate = fromDate.plus(i * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
        ZonedDateTime maxDate = fromDate.plus((i + 1) * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
        reachedDate = toDate.isBefore(maxDate);
        buckets.add(new DateBucket(minDate.toInstant(), maxDate.toInstant()));
    }
    return buckets;
}
}
```

As an example the following input:

```
fromDate -> 2020-12-07 00:00:00
toDate -> 2020-12-07 00:00:03
bucketSize -> 1
bucketSizeUnit -> ChronoUnit.SECONDS
```

Returns the following `DateBucket` list:

```
0. DateBucket(from = 2020-12-07  05:00:00, to = 2020-12-07 05:00:01)
1. DateBucket(from = 2020-12-07  05:00:01, to = 2020-12-07 05:00:02)
2. DateBucket(from = 2020-12-07  05:00:02, to = 2020-12-07 05:00:03)
3. DateBucket(from = 2020-12-07  05:00:03, to = 2020-12-07 05:00:04)
```

So, How can I refactor the `bucketize` method using the same logic but with Java 8 Streams?

Comment: Note that you are creating each ZonedDateTime and Instant object twice. But you can do the same with a stream like `return LongStream.rangeClosed(0, fromDate.until(toDate, bucketSizeUnit)) .mapToObj(l -> new DateBucket(fromDate.plus(l, bucketSizeUnit).toInstant(), fromDate.plus(l + 1, bucketSizeUnit).toInstant())) .collect(Collectors.toList());`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
public static List<DateBucket> bucketize(
        ZonedDateTime fromDate, 
        ZonedDateTime toDate, 
        int bucketSize, 
        ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit
    ) {
    
    var result = new ArrayList<DateBucket>();
    IntStream.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .mapToObj(i -> fromDate.plus(i * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit))
            .takeWhile(d -> d.isBefore(toDate))
            .map(d -> d.toInstant())
            .reduce((min, max) -> {
                result.add(new DateBucket(min, max));
                return max;
            });
    return result;
}
```

While this reduction function could be considered an abuse of the stream API (reduction functions are supposed to be stateless and associative, which ours is not, but it should be safe in this case since we know that the stream is sequential, and will thus iterate in order), the stream API doesn't seem to offer a more straightforward API to combine adjacent stream elements.

That said, I'd probably prefer your imperative implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The line of thought here is that you want to stream the values needed to create the buckets, then `map` and `collect` them. A stream of `ZonedDateTimes` will do and you can use a `Spliterator` to create the stream. This seems to be one possible implementation which is basic and doesn't support parallelization, but does seem to work.

```
public class ZonedDateTimeSpliterator implements Spliterator<ZonedDateTime> {
    private final ZonedDateTime fromDate;
    private final ZonedDateTime toDate;
    private final int bucketSize;
    private final ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit;
    private ZonedDateTime currentDate;

    public ZonedDateTimeSpliterator(ZonedDateTime fromDate, ZonedDateTime toDate, int bucketSize,
            ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
        this.toDate = toDate;
        this.bucketSize = bucketSize;
        this.bucketSizeUnit = bucketSizeUnit;
        currentDate = fromDate.truncatedTo(bucketSizeUnit);
    }

    public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super ZonedDateTime> action) {
        while (currentDate.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit).isBefore(toDate)) {
            getNext(action);
        }
    }

    private void getNext(Consumer<? super ZonedDateTime> action) {
        action.accept(currentDate);
        currentDate = currentDate.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super ZonedDateTime> action) {
        if (currentDate.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit).isBefore(toDate)) {
            getNext(action);
            return true;
        } else // cannot advance
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<ZonedDateTime> trySplit() {
        // implement for parallel processing
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return Duration.between(fromDate.truncatedTo(bucketSizeUnit), toDate.truncatedTo(bucketSizeUnit))
                .get(bucketSizeUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return ORDERED | SIZED | IMMUTABLE;
    }
}
```

Then you simply `stream` the values, `map` the buckets, and `collect` the list.

```
private List<DateBucket> doThing(ZonedDateTime fromDate, ZonedDateTime toDate, int bucketSize,
        ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {
    return StreamSupport
            .stream(() -> new ZonedDateTimeSpliterator(fromDate, toDate, bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit),
                    Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE, false)
            .map(currentDate -> new DateBucket(currentDate.toInstant(),
                    currentDate.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit).toInstant()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: You could use a simple `LongStream` like in the comment to the question or implement a `Spliterator` like suggested here. A `Spliterator` will allow you to move to parallelization if you want though I don't think this example justifies it. Mostly I looked at the question and I thought "Wow, that could be done with a spliterator". I don't have much (read: no) practice implementing `Spliterators` so I used this answer as an chance to practice. Readers choice.